# pandas pivot dataframe structure

Tags: python, pandas

**raw data**

[image]

**pivot table**
[image]

**question**

how can I replace *industryName* with *tradeDate* and remove that blank row? I want to make it look like:

the screenshot below is created by [IPython-Dashboard](https://github.com/litaotao/IPython-Dashboard)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reset_index` to convert you index to a regular column.

```
data_pivot.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

`tradeDate` is the name of your index.  You can remove it via:

```
data_pivot.index.name = None
```

`industryName` is the name of your columns.  You can change that be equal to `tradeDate` via:

```
data_pivot.columns.name = 'tradeDate'
```